# Segmentation error in vectors in C++

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I have a vector called `cpatches` which is not empty and contains at least one object `cv::Point3i(0,0,0)`. Below is my code which gives segmentation error. Code works perfectly fine until it reaches the line `r2 = objects.front().y`, which then gives segmentation error and abort the code.

I'm trying to separate objects that are separated by `cv::Point3i(0,0,0)` to another vector called `objects`. In sorting, `compare_row` and `compare_col`, works perfectly fine. (it returns `a.y > b.y` and `a.z > b.z` respectively)

Code is as below.

```
for (int i = 0; i < cpatches.size(); i++) {
    cv::Point3i npoint = cpatches[i];
    std::vector<cv::Point3i> objects;
    std::cout << npoint << std::endl;
    if (npoint.x != 1 && npoint.y != 1 && npoint.z != 1) {
        objects.push_back(npoint);
    } else {
        std::sort(objects.begin(), objects.end(), compare_row);
        int r1, r2, c1, c2;
        r2 = objects.front().y;
        r1 = objects.back().y;
        std::sort(objects.begin(), objects.end(), compare_col);
        c2 = objects.front().y;
        c1 = objects.back().y;
        cv::rectangle(display_obstacles, cv::Point(r1, c1), cv::Point(r2, c2), CV_RGB(0, 255, 0));
        std::cout << "hhh" << r1 << ", " << c1 << "; " << r2 << ", " << c2 << "; ";
        objects.clear();
    }
}
```

Can you help me identify what error I make when calling the first and last elements of the vector?

Comment: When `npoint` has a `1` in either `x,y,z` then there are no objects in `objects`.

Comment: What if the first `npoint` in `cpatches` is going to else branch? The `objects` are going to be empty and on `objects.front()` you'll get segfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a `vector` instance is empty, then it is undefined behaviour to us either its `front()` or `back()` methods (both of which assume the presence of at least one element). This is almost certainly what is causing your problem.

In this scenario hitting your `else` clause before any elements have been pushed onto `objects`. One easy way to prevent this is to change the line:

```
} else {
```

to

```
} else if (!objects.empty()) {
```

Comment: But why is objects vector becomes empty ? Even elements are added using  objects.push_back(npoint);,  the vector is empty ? Can you explain me that ?

Comment: OKay I got it, std::vector<cv::Point3i> objects; should be defined outside the for loop. Otherwise it always creates a new instance of the vector, which makes it a empty vector for any i.